# Open and read sequential XML files with unknown files names in Python

Tags: python

I wish to read incoming XML files that have no specific name (e.g. date/time naming) to extract values and perform particular tasks.
I can step through the files but am having trouble opening them and reading them.

What I have that works is:-

```
 import os
 path = 'directory/'
 listing = os.listdir(path)
 for infile in listing:
      print infile
```

But when I add the following to try and read the files it errors saying No such file or directory.

```
      file = open(infile,'r')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Excellent, thank you all for your answers and explaination, very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the path to file too:

```
file = open(os.path.join(path,infile),'r')
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` provides the base names, not absolute paths. You'll need to do `os.path.join(path, infile)` instead of just `infile` (that may still be a relative path, which should be fine; if you needed an absolute path, you'd feed it through `os.path.abspath`).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to joining the directory path and filename as in the other answers, you can use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module. This can also be handy when your directories might contain other (non-XML) files that you don't want to process:

```
import glob
for infile in glob.glob('directory/*.xml'):
    print infile
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to join the directory path and filename, using

```
os.path.join(path, infile)
```

Also use the path without the / :

```
path = 'directory'
```

Something like this (Not optimized, just a small change in your code):

```
import os
 path = 'directory'
 listing = os.listdir(path)
 for infile in listing:
      print infile
      file_abs = os.path.join(path, infile)
      file = open(file_abs,'r')
```